# Python pointers/advice

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the question that was asked and below that I’ll paste the code I have so far.  Any pointers would be great.  Please keep in mind this is only my second week with python (or any programming for that matter) so I have no idea what I’m doing.  How would you code this?  Anyways, any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED!

I’d kind of like to figure it out with % rather than subtracting everything also, but doesn’t really matter either way.

**If I leave my house at 6:52 am and run 1 mile at an easy pace (8:15 per mile), then 3 miles at tempo (7:12 per mile) and 1 mile at easy pace again, what time do I get home for breakfast?**

```
 seconds = 1
 hours = seconds / (60*60)
 seconds = seconds - hours*60*60
 minutes = seconds / 60
 seconds = seconds - minutes *60

 time_left_house = 6 * hours + 52 * minutes

 miles_run_easy_pace = 2 * (8 * minutes + 15 * seconds)

 miles_run_fast_pace = 3 * (7 * minutes + 12 * seconds)


 total_time_run = miles_run_easy_pace + miles_run_fast_pace + time_left_house

 print total_time_run, "Total time run: " , hours, 'Hours: ', minutes, 'Minutes: ', seconds, 'Seconds: ‘
```

FYI, i'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: I agree with exploring the `datetime` module and `timedelta`s.  There's quite a bit in the python standard libraries that will simplify these types of projects for you.

Comment: I don't really know what kind of answer you're looking for here. But maybe you wanted codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3):

Likely you need to use classes from `datetime` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html , for example [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Here's the example :)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
>>> time_left_house = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(hour = 6, minute = 52))
>>> miles_run_easy_pace = 2 * timedelta(minutes = 8, seconds = 15)
>>> miles_run_fast_pace = 3 * timedelta(minutes = 7, seconds = 12)
>>> total_time_run = time_left_house + miles_run_easy_pace + miles_run_fast_pace
>>> print total_time_run
2014-01-31 07:30:06
>>>
```

Comment: This would serve better as a comment unless you add some code demonstrating the use of `timedelta`'s.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Thanks for the links I'll check them out.

Comment: Well, the given python docs page has more examples that I can provide :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up your code. The part at the beginning looks like something like the code that splits `total_time_run` into hours, minutes and seconds

It's probably a good idea to work out everything as seconds. I've used uppercase for those conversion factors to distinguish that they are constants

```
SECONDS = 1
MINUTES = 60 * SECONDS
HOURS = 60 * MINUTES

# All these results are in seconds

time_left_house = 6 * HOURS + 52 * MINUTES

miles_run_easy_pace = 2 * (8 * MINUTES + 15 * SECONDS)

miles_run_fast_pace = 3 * (7 * MINUTES + 12 * SECONDS)

total_time_run = miles_run_easy_pace + miles_run_fast_pace + time_left_house

# So we now have a big number of seconds to split into hours/minutes/seconds

hours = total_time_run // HOURS

# the left over part is minutes and seconds (still in seconds)

part_hour = total_time_run % HOURS
minutes = part_hour // MINUTES
seconds = part_hour % MINUTES

print "Total time run: {}, Hours: {}, Minutes: {}, Seconds: {}".format(
    total_time_run, hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: You are awesome!  That helped me understand a lot!  I'm still a bit confused on a couple of things.  One, what exactly does the dbl // do?  From what I remember something about floor division, nt sure what that means though.  second, I'm not 100% clear on the part_hour section.  And last one I swear....when I run this it states the correct answer but also the number 27006 after total time run, I'm not sure what that number is or how it ends up there.  I know my question are probably stupid lol, just keep in mind I'm very new.